# Data view for A/B Tests?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export, jobs, ab-testing

I'm trying to export our Job data to a data warehouse and it'd be helpful to know which of the jobs we're exporting are associated with AB tests. I can definitely see that Marketing Cloud has some other view to associate Jobs with AB tests, but I haven't seen that data exposed in the documentation. Is this something that I can pull via Query, or do I have to rely on manual exports? Do I need to just put all AB Tests in their own tracking folder and filter by Category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an exact solution but you can try this:

1- Please go to Tracking - Sends and tick A/B Test in the grid.

[image]

2- Then you can click on that column to see all A/B tests and please move them in a folder.

[image]

3- Now you can use this SQL to get all the jobIDs in this folder/category:

```
SELECT j.JobID
FROM _Sent s
JOIN _Job j on s.JobID = j.JobID 
WHERE j.Category = 'Folder Name'
```

Comment: I was afraid of that - thanks for sharing your workaround. I've requested that the Marketing Cloud product team expose this data view for us. Please vote for it here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cRh3QAE